# What is the best adhesive to repair broken towel bracket?

Tags: adhesive

The metal bracket that holds the towel bar rods in place fell and broke in two pieces (exactly where they are joined together). It was a clean break and just needs to be glued together. Any recommendations on what to use on a metal towel bar?

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement stackexchange!  I'd use 2-part epoxy for gluing metal.  Make sure the surfaces are very clean (e.g. use denatured alcohol).  But I'm dubious that the glue will hold in something like a bracket where the surfaces are small.  Pictures would help a lot.

Comment: a bracket is one piece of metal, i don't see how it could break in two. you probably need to loosen the retaining screw, attach, then re-tighten; no glue involved. i 2nd the motion for a picture, or at least a better description of what you now have.

Comment: Are you sure it is not plastic made to look like metal?  Only very cheap badly made metal will crack apart just falling to the floor.

Comment: Unless this is a special and expensive towel rack, it would be better to replace it with a new towel rack.

Comment: Brazing or silver soldering, but that would depend on the metal, and might also damage the finish/plating. Low temperature solder  (plumbing solder, which may also have silver these days, but which is not what's generally meant by "silver solder") would likely be stronger than most glues, and since it requires less heat is less likely to cause you to melt some of the possible metals it might be cast from, or to do as much damage to the surface finish.

Comment: please post a clear, well lit, closeup picture of the two broken pieces ... place them on a sheet of paper before you take the picture

Comment: it's possible that it was always three pieces of metal and being attached to the wall was all that ever made them hang together.